# Convergence of a split series.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have a question considering the convergence of the complex series: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}z^n $$,
where $ a_{n} = \begin{cases} k^k, & \mbox{if } n=k^2 \\ 0, & \mbox{otherwise }  \end{cases}$.

How do we approach these situations? Should I plug $n=k^2$ and $a_{n}=k^k$ and apply the root or ratio test? Or should I work with the formal definition of the radius of convergence?

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\begin{cases}(k^k)^{1/k^2}=\sqrt[k]k&\text{ if }n=k^2\text{ for some }k\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$So, $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}=1$ and therefore the radius of convergence of the series converges is $1$. Actually, it converges if and only if $\lvert z\rvert<1$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $\sqrt[n]{a_n} = (k^k)^{(1/k^2)} = k^{(1/k)} \to 1$ in the first case.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but, isn't it equal to 1? I concluded that it's equal to $\sqrt[k]{k}$..

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wanted to make sure that we approach these problems this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of harmonic numbers and digamma functions, then

S1=∑n=0p1n+1=ψ(p+2)+γ=Hp+1
S2=∑n=0p1n+z=ψ(p+z+1)−ψ(z)
Now, considering the asymptotics for large values of p
S1−S2=(ψ(z)+γ)+1−zp+z2+z−22p2+O(1p3)
which make
∑n=0∞(1n+1−1z+n)=ψ(z)+γ
You will find here some special values of the digamma function.

Comment: Your answer is very difficult to read. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).